# "note: declared here" - build error during PHP installing on RHEL

Tags: php, c, docker, build, rhel

I try to install PHP on RHEL 8.5. I use Docker 20.10.7 (build 20.10.7-0ubuntu5~20.04.2). My procedure looks like this:

```
git clone git://github.com/phpenv/phpenv.git ~/.phpenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.phpenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
echo 'eval "$(phpenv init -)"' >> ~/.bash_profile

export PATH="$HOME/.phpenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(phpenv init -)"
git clone https://github.com/php-build/php-build $(phpenv root)/plugins/php-build
phpenv install 7.1.33
```

And I get error like this:

```
[Info]: Loaded extension plugin
[Info]: Loaded apc Plugin.
[Info]: Loaded composer Plugin.
[Info]: Loaded github Plugin.
[Info]: Loaded uprofiler Plugin.
[Info]: Loaded xdebug Plugin.
[Info]: Loaded xhprof Plugin.
[Info]: Loaded zendopcache Plugin.
[Info]: php.ini-production gets used as php.ini
[Info]: Building 7.1.33 into /root/.phpenv/versions/7.1.33
[Downloading]: https://secure.php.net/distributions/php-7.1.33.tar.bz2
[Preparing]: /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33
[Compiling]: /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33

-----------------
|  BUILD ERROR  |
-----------------

Here are the last 10 lines from the log:

-----------------------------------------
                 from /usr/include/openssl/err.h:13,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/php_openssl.h:69,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:32:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1890:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_2_server_method(void))
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:886: ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apprentice.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
-----------------------------------------

The full Log is available at '/tmp/php-build.7.1.33.20220214075100.log'.
[Warn]: Aborting build.
```

Logs from `/tmp/php-build.7.1.33.20220214075100.log`:

```
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
/tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c: In function ‘php_select_crypto_method’:
/tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:952:3: warning: ‘TLSv1_client_method’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return is_client ? TLSv1_client_method() : TLSv1_server_method();
   ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/err.h:13,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/php_openssl.h:69,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:32:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1879:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_client_method(void))
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:952:3: warning: ‘TLSv1_server_method’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return is_client ? TLSv1_client_method() : TLSv1_server_method();
   ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/err.h:13,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/php_openssl.h:69,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:32:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1878:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_server_method(void))
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:955:3: warning: ‘TLSv1_1_client_method’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return is_client ? TLSv1_1_client_method() : TLSv1_1_server_method();
   ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/err.h:13,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/php_openssl.h:69,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:32:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1885:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_1_client_method(void))
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:955:3: warning: ‘TLSv1_1_server_method’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return is_client ? TLSv1_1_client_method() : TLSv1_1_server_method();
   ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/err.h:13,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/php_openssl.h:69,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:32:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1884:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_1_server_method(void))
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:963:3: warning: ‘TLSv1_2_client_method’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return is_client ? TLSv1_2_client_method() : TLSv1_2_server_method();
   ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/err.h:13,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/php_openssl.h:69,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:32:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1891:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_2_client_method(void))
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:963:3: warning: ‘TLSv1_2_server_method’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]
   return is_client ? TLSv1_2_client_method() : TLSv1_2_server_method();
   ^~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/openssl/opensslconf.h:42,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/e_os2.h:13,
                 from /usr/include/openssl/err.h:13,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/php_openssl.h:69,
                 from /tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:32:
/usr/include/openssl/ssl.h:1890:1: note: declared here
 DEPRECATEDIN_1_1_0(__owur const SSL_METHOD *TLSv1_2_server_method(void))
 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:886: ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apprentice.lo] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Any ideas what is going on here?

Comment: I would assume the `note: declareed here` part is just an extension of the real error message which seems to be chopped in your log. You should check what the full log tells us about that error.

Comment: I added logs from `/tmp/php-build.7.1.33.20220214075100.log`, but the error looks the same.

Comment: No, now you can see the initial warning: `warning: ‘TLSv1_2_server_method’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]` And also warnings for multiple functions.

Comment: And generally, you should start reading your warnings from top to bottom. Starting with this: `configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
/tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c: In function ‘php_select_crypto_method’:
/tmp/php-build/source/7.1.33/ext/openssl/xp_ssl.c:952:3: warning: ‘TLSv1_client_method’ is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]` Unfortunately I don't have a solution for you.